# Replacing 0 by class mean

Tags: r

I want to replace 0 values by mean value of that column (for same class). Eg.

```
a1  class
0   0
1   0
3   0
0   1
1   1
5   1
```

should be converted to

```
a1  class
2   0
1   0
3   0
3   1
1   1
5   1
```

Now, I am able to find the mean but unable to select 0s of same class so as to replace them by the mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After initially misreading the question, here's a lengthy option in base R:

```
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$class), function(d) {
  d$a1[d$a1 == 0] <- mean(d$a1[d$a1 != 0]); d
}))
rownames(df) <- NULL   # to turn the rownames to normal numbering
```

Some explanation:

- `split(df, df$class)` splits the data into chunks with same `class` into a list
- Using `lapply` on that list, you do for each list element, denoted by `d`: subset column a1 where a1 is 0 and replace values with the mean of a1 where a1 is not 0
- Then you use `do.call(rbind, ...)` on the resulting list to turn it back into a data.frame

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wanted to replace by integer value so I took floor(mean..). Could you please provide some info about how it works or point me to appropriate place so I could accept it.

Comment: @Peeyush, I added some explanation. Generally, you can always find information about R functions by typing `?functionname`, for example, `?split` for information on the function `split`.

Comment: If you're going to use `split()`, i might recommend `unsplit()` rather than `do.call(rbind, ...)` to put things back together again.

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,.(a1=replace(a1, a1==0, mean(a1[a1!=0]))) , class]
```

Comment: I guess you could `setDT(df)[, .(a1 = replace(a1, a1==0, mean(a1[a1!=0]))) , class]` for nicer output, but nice trick to avoid this annoying error if you'll do `a1:=` :)

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to avoid the `replace` with `:=`, looks like that is difficult for this one.

Comment: @Arun Thanks, but I guess that would replace all the elements in `a1` with the mean by class

Answer (score 1):

If this is your input data frame

```
dd<-data.frame(
     a1 = c(0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 5L), 
     class = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L)
)
```

you can use `ave`. For example

```
dd$a1 <- with(dd, ave(a1, class, 
    FUN=function(x) ifelse(x==0, mean(x[x!=0]), x)))
```

Comment: I got the following error when trying your solution.. `Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
  unique() applies only to vectors`

Comment: @Peeyush Did you copy/paste exactly what I wrote?? Make sure you have the `FUN=` named parameter in the call to `ave()`.

Comment: ahh.. my bad. This seems to convert values to `float` from `int`. Any way to maybe use floor or something instead..? Also, could you point to a place where i can find more info about with or ave. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Yeah, the problem with `ave()` is that it converts the results to the same class as the first parameter. You can read more about it on the `ave()` help page. Essentially what `ave` is doing is a spilt/unsplit so you could do `with(dd, unsplit(lapply(split(a1, class), function(x) ifelse(x==0, mean(x[x!=0]), x)), class))` but that's a bit uglier.

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(class) %>%
  mutate(a1 = ifelse(a1 == 0, mean(a1[a1 != 0]), a1))
```